# Template Does not exsist-heroku django

Tags: python, django, heroku, deployment

I have been working on a django application by following the coreyMS tutorials.Now it is at the deployment stage.I tried to deploy the app using heroku. The app gets deployed and all the blog apps templates are fine.But the users app templates are not getting rendered.Any help will be appreciated.Thanks in advance!

My settings.py file:

````
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
         'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]```

Only the templates of blog are getting rendered.I am having two apps-blog and users.
in both the apps i have the templates in the following way:
app->templates->appname->.htmlfiles

One is getting rendered while the other is not..
````

Comment: Please show the full traceback, and the view that is giving the error.

Comment: Well the issue has been solved.. I had to keep a single app instead of two apps..i just moved all the files from one app to another app..and the issue was resolved..i still don't know why that happens..

Comment: Glad you got it working another way. I can’t tell what the problem was because you didn’t post the information I asked for.